Mikhlin, Marcinkiewicz theorem on weighted space $L^p$ spaces.
This theorem is in  D. Guidetti, “Vector valued Fourier multipliers and applications,” Bruno Pini Mathematical Analysis Seminar, Seminars 2010 (2010). It is a variant (I think, a easier variant) of Mikhlin theorem.
Theorem 2. Let $m\in C^n(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \left\{0\right\})$
be such that, for every $\alpha\leq (1,\ldots, 1)\in \mathbb{N}_0^n$ multi-index, for some $C$ constant, for every $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \left\{0\right\}$
\begin{align}
|\xi^{\alpha}D^{\alpha}m(\xi)|\leq C
\end{align}
Then $m$ is a Fourier multiplier for $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $1\leq p\leq \infty$.
Question. Is there an analogously (easier) for weighted $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ spaces?
Thanks.
